# Flask: get image via post

Tags: python, image, upload, flask

Hi I have the following html

```
<form action="classify_upload" method="post" id="upload-form">
    <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="imagefile"/>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

And in my `flask` webapp I have the following rule:

```
@webapp.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    try:
        imagefile = flask.request.files('imagefile', '')
        ...
    except Exception as err:
        ...
```

But this is giving me the following exception

```
'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable
```

I have no idea what this means or why it is occurring. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to add `enctype = 'multipart/form-data'` on the form tag to be like `<form action="classify_upload" method="post" id="upload-form" enctype = 'multipart/form-data>` without that attribute flask will throw 400 bad request

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this line:

```
imagefile = flask.request.files('imagefile', '')
```

to:

```
imagefile = flask.request.files.get('imagefile', '')
```

Comment: Just a quick question. What if I want to upload this `imagefile` to another url? Can I use something like `blob.upload(imagefile)`

Comment: @pythondumb Not sure exactly what you mean but perhaps something like this:
https://gist.github.com/leongjinqwen/9d9a2d58bf2fb923658820559a88a5ec